# Create date (month) exeption for R script

Tags: r, rvest, jsonlite

I am trying to access and download some data from a website with API connection. The challenge is that the instrument I want to trace is a future with the usual convention (which is that each month corresponds to a letter, followed by the year). The instrument root name is JKM, the structure is JKMMYY (M for month, Y for year). Keep in mind that the month is represented by a letter.So, for instance the contract for January19 would be JKMF19 (because F represents January). So far so good.. I applied the following logic:

```
monthsymbol <- c("F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "M", "N", "Q", "U", "V", "X", "Z")
```

and then applied

```
monthsymbol[month(Sys.Date())+1])
```

This works well unless I am in December, where I need to apply the first month of the next year. I am not quite sure what is the best way to implement that, maybe an if clause? Any input is welcome!

I add the code below, so you get the idea..

Many thanks in advance!

```
library("lubridate")
library("jsonlite")
library("dplyr")
library("xts")
library("dygraphs")
library("rvest")    


##########################

#JKM historical data ####

apikey <- "a35e82bda46a34f21xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
current_year <- unlist(strsplit(x = as.character(year(Sys.Date())),split = "0"))[2]
todays_date <- gsub(x = as.character(Sys.Date()), pattern = "-", replacement = "")

#api in json format
json_file <- paste0("https://marketdata.websol.barchart.com/getHistory.json?apikey=",apikey,paste0("&symbol=JKM", monthsymbol[month(Sys.Date())+1]),current_year,"&type=daily&startDate=20160901&endDate=",todays_date,"&maxRecords=750")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ifelse` and check the value of `month` and accordingly `paste` the string. If it's value is 12 (December) we increment the year as well.

```
library(lubridate)

ifelse(month(x) == 12,
        paste0(root_name, monthsymbol[1], year + 1),
        paste0(root_name, monthsymbol[month(x) + 1], year))

 #[1] "JKMG19" "JKMX19" "JKMZ19" "JKMF20"
```

In the above command replace `x` with `Sys.Date()` in your script.

**data**

```
x <- as.Date(c("2018-01-09", "2018-10-06", "2018-11-02", "2018-12-21"))
year <- 19
root_name <- "JKM"
```